# create a table relation on itself in mysql

Tags: mysql, foreign-keys, relation, join

I have a table like so:

```
 CREATE TABLE `jngi_category` (
      `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
      `Name` varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      `parent` int(11) NOT NULL,
      PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

and i want, when a parent delete all of it's child delete so.
if there is any relations that defines by foreign-key so it do that automatically is good.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add a foreign key constraint on this column `parent` with `ON DELETE CASCADE`:

```
CONSTRAINT `FK_ParentCategory` FOREIGN KEY (`parent`)
REFERENCES jngi_category(id) ON DELETE CASCADE ON UPDATE CASCADE
```

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/c8a3e/1)

Answer (score 2):

Try this sql

```
CREATE TABLE jngi_category (
      id int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
      Name varchar(50) NOT NULL,
      parent int(11),
      PRIMARY KEY (id),
      foreign key (parent) references jngi_category(id) on delete cascade
    ) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=3 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 ;
```